# New data.table column returns nth largest value in a row

Tags: r, data.table

My data looks similar to this:

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(rank=c(3,4,2,1),`1`=rnorm(4),`2`=rnorm(4),`3`=rnorm(4),`4`=rnorm(4),`5`=rnorm(4),`6`=rnorm(4))

   rank          1          2          3           4           5           6
1:    3 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814 -0.62124058 -0.01619026  0.91897737
2:    4  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884 -2.21469989  0.94383621  0.78213630
3:    2 -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812  1.12493092  0.82122120  0.07456498
4:    1  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432 -0.04493361  0.59390132 -1.98935170
```

I would like to add a new column `rank_match` that finds the nth (taken from the `rank` column) largest value in the row from columns named `1` to `6`.  For instance, the first line would look for the 3rd largest value in the row from columns named `1` to `6` which is 0.3295078.

Something like these (but of course they doesn't work):

```
dt[,rank_match := (sort(`1`:`6`, decreasing = TRUE)[rank])]
dt[,rank_match := (sort(.SD, decreasing = TRUE)[rank]), .SDcols=`1`:`6`]
```

The output should look similar to this:

```
   rank          1          2          3           4           5           6 rank_match
1:    3 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814 -0.62124058 -0.01619026  0.91897737  0.3295078
2:    4  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884 -2.21469989  0.94383621  0.78213630 -0.3053884
3:    2 -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812  1.12493092  0.82122120  0.07456498  1.1249309
4:    1  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432 -0.04493361  0.59390132 -1.98935170  1.5952808
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt[, rank_match := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) x[order(-x)][rank]), by = rank, .SDcols = `1`:`6`]
dt
   rank          1          2          3           4           5           6 rank_match
1:    3 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814 -0.62124058 -0.01619026  0.91897737  0.3295078
2:    4  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884 -2.21469989  0.94383621  0.78213630 -0.3053884
3:    2 -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812  1.12493092  0.82122120  0.07456498  1.1249309
4:    1  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432 -0.04493361  0.59390132 -1.98935170  1.5952808
```

Comment: Thanks @snoram  this answer seems the most readable to me, although all others work as well.

Answer (score 3):

One option is group by the sequence of rows, specify the columns of interest from column 2 onwards, `unlist`, the Subset of Data.table, `sort` in decreasing order, subset the value based on the 'rank' column and assign it to 'rank_match'

```
dt[, rank_match := sort(unlist(.SD), decreasing = TRUE)[rank], 
           1:nrow(dt), .SDcols = 2:ncol(dt) ]
dt
#   rank          1          2          3           4           5           6 rank_match
#1:    3 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814 -0.62124058 -0.01619026  0.91897737  0.3295078
#2:    4  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884 -2.21469989  0.94383621  0.78213630 -0.3053884
#3:    2 -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812  1.12493092  0.82122120  0.07456498  1.1249309
#4:    1  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432 -0.04493361  0.59390132 -1.98935170  1.5952808
```

---

Another option would be to `melt` and then get the corresponding value of the 'value' column

```
out <- melt(dt, id.var = c('rn', 'rank'))[order(-value), 
                  value[rank[1]] , .(rn)][order(rn)]$V1
dt[, rank_match := out][, rn := NULL][]
```

Or a compact approach suggested by @IceCreamToucan

```
dt[, rank_match := melt(.SD, 'rank')[, value[order(-value)[rank]], rank]$V1]
```

---

Or use `pmap` (from `purrr`) to loop through the rows

```
library(purrr)
dt[, rank_match := pmap_dbl(.SD, ~ c(...) %>% 
                                    {sort(-.[-1])[.[1]]})]
```

Answer (score 3):

`apply` the indicated function on each row of `.SD`:

```
dt[, rank_match := apply(.SD, 1, function(x) -sort(-x[-1])[x[1]])]
```

giving:

```
   rank          1          2          3           4           5           6 rank_match
1:    3 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814 -0.62124058 -0.01619026  0.91897737  0.3295078
2:    4  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884 -2.21469989  0.94383621  0.78213630 -0.3053884
3:    2 -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812  1.12493092  0.82122120  0.07456498  1.1249309
4:    1  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432 -0.04493361  0.59390132 -1.98935170  1.5952808
```

Comment: Another great solution that works well @G. Grothendieck Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`DescTools::Large` returns the `n`th largest elements from a vector without sorting the whole thing. Not sure how this compares to `dt[order(-value)[rank], ...]`.

```
library(DescTools)
library(data.table)

dt[, rank_match := melt(dt, 'rank')[, Large(value, rank)[1], rank]$V1]


#    rank          1          2          3           4           5           6 rank_match
# 1:    3 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814 -0.62124058 -0.01619026  0.91897737  0.3295078
# 2:    4  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884 -2.21469989  0.94383621  0.78213630 -0.3053884
# 3:    2 -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812  1.12493092  0.82122120  0.07456498  1.1249309
# 4:    1  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432 -0.04493361  0.59390132 -1.98935170  1.5952808
```

Note: If some rows have the same rank you must use the `rn`/ row number logic as in akrun's answer.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) implementation (with two variants):

```
# option 1
dt[melt(dt, id = 1)[, value[frank(-value) == .BY], by = rank]
   , on = .(rank)
   , rank_match := V1 ]

# option 2
dt[, rank_match := melt(dt, id = 1)[, value[frank(-value) == .BY], by = rank]$V1 ]
```

which both give the desired result:

> ```
> > dt
>    rank          1          2          3           4           5           6 rank_match
> 1:    3 -0.6264538  0.3295078  0.5757814 -0.62124058 -0.01619026  0.91897737  0.3295078
> 2:    4  0.1836433 -0.8204684 -0.3053884 -2.21469989  0.94383621  0.78213630 -0.3053884
> 3:    2 -0.8356286  0.4874291  1.5117812  1.12493092  0.82122120  0.07456498  1.1249309
> 4:    1  1.5952808  0.7383247  0.3898432 -0.04493361  0.59390132 -1.98935170  1.5952808
> ```